# Android Development - OnTouchListener - How to Use?

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

I was wondering how one uses `OnTouchListener`. (I'm using Android Studio.)

This is my code and when I press the "Vibrate" button, the button image doesn't change to it's pressed state:

```
vibrateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_vibrate);
    vibrationInstance = (Vibrator) getSystemService(this.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrateButtonPressed = false;
    if (!(vibrationInstance.hasVibrator())) {
        vibrateButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
    vibrateButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                vibrationInstance.cancel();
            }
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                vibrationInstance.vibrate(vibrationPattern, 0);
            }
            return false;
        }


    });
```

Is this how one uses `OnTouchListener` and what is the need for `return false;`? Thanks!

Comment: Well that's *a* way of using `OnTouchListener`. As for `return false` - the method is declared to return a `boolean` (to say whether or not the listener has consumed the event).

Comment: But this crashes my app... so the syntax correct?

Comment: Added that it crashes my app to the question.

Comment: So what does the log look like? There should be an exception in there, which will explain why it's crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your application is crashing because you forgot to add the permission to the manifest file. Make sure this is in it: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />`

And, by the way, if you want to receive all the touch events occuring to the View, you should `return true` in the `OnTouchListener`.

Comment: It didn't work. It stopped it from crashing, but it didn't make it vibrate. :(

Comment: `return true` like I said in my answer. And it will only vibrate on press, since your only calling `vibrate` then the action is `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`